# Solve $z^3+12z^2+30z+4$

Tags: complex-numbers

Solve $z^3+12z^2+30z+4$

The question tells me to use an algebraic substitution to change it into the form $u^3+cu+d$ and then use a trigonometric substitution to solve but I have don't understand how to do this.

Thanks so much everyone in advance

Comment: Substituting $z \leftarrow 2 \sqrt6 \cos(x) - 4$ and using $\cos(3x) = 4\cos^3(x) - 3 \cos(x)$ reduces this expression to $12 ( \sqrt6 \cos(3x) +1)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This substitution is called the **Tschirnhaus transformation.** For any degree $n$ polynomial $az^n + b z^{n-1} + \dotsb + c$, you may substitute the change of variables $z=u-\frac{b}{na}$ to eliminate the next to leading term.

For example, substituting $z=u-\frac{b}{2a}$ into the quadratic $az^2+bz+c$ yields $au^2 + k,$ where $k=\frac{4ac-b^2}{4a}.$ In this case, the transformation yields what is often called **completing the square.**

For your cubic polynomial, you should substitute $z=u-\frac{12}{3}=u-4.$ Unlike in the quadratic case, it doesn't completely isolate the variable of your cubic. It only gets rid of the quadratic term. Once you've done this transformation to your cubic, and gotten rid of its quadratic term, it is called a **depressed cubic.** Your polynomial will become $$(u-4)^3+12(u-4)^2+30(u-4)+4 = u^3 - 18 u + 12.$$

To complete the reduction with a trigonometric substitution, as WimC says in the comment, you should compare the cubic and linear terms of the depressed cubic to the triple angle formula $\cos 3x=4\cos^3 x-3\cos x.$ So if we make a substitution $u=a\cos w$, our polynomial becomes $a^3\cos^3w-18a\cos w+12.$ To be in triple angle form we need $a^3/(18a)=4/3,$ or $a^2=24,$ so $a=2\sqrt{6}.$

Then the polynomial is $$u^3 - 18 u + 12 = 48\sqrt{6}\cos^3w-36\sqrt{6}\cos w + 12$$

from which we factor out $48\sqrt{6}/4=12\sqrt{6}$ from the first two terms:

$$12\sqrt{6}(4\cos^3w-3\cos w)+12 = 12\sqrt{6}\cos(3w)+12.$$

Comment: That substitution is considered a Tschirhausen transformation? I thought only transformations that remove multiple terms were called that....

Comment: @Crescendo Hmm it's how I learned it, but wikipedia's entry does not confirm, so I'm not sure. Can someone confirm? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tschirnhaus_transformation

Comment: https://brilliant.org/wiki/cardano-method/

Answer (score 3):

Let $t = z+4$, one then has $$(t-4)^3 + 12(t-4)^2 + 30(t-4) + 4 = 0$$

$$t^3-18t+12=0$$